# Slow start-up of large programs

Tags: windows, optimization, loading

The following program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    static char a[1 << 28] = {1};
    printf("%d\n", a[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiles on Windows 7 x64 to this executable

```
19/06/2015  21:57       268,519,936 a.exe
```

Which takes 5.6 seconds to run, even when run several times in succession to make sure it's cached in memory.

I would have expected Windows to either read in the entire executable at the start (in which case the machine is capable of stream reading at many hundreds of megabytes per second) or page in only the parts that are needed (in which case only a few kilobytes should have been read); either way, the program should run in a fraction of a second. If you tweak the array size, runtime is proportional to the size of the executable, so Windows behaves as though it's reading the entire executable but by some very slow method.

What's the reason for this behaviour, and is there anything that can be done about it?

Comment: Is this a question about optimising your code, or about the behaviour of Windows? One is trivial and the other is off-topic.

Comment: Its about profiling his anti-malware.  Sad numbers.

Comment: @HoboSapiens Obviously the test program is a stand-in for large programs that are large because they contain useful code and data. My question is whether there is anything one can do as a programmer, writing a large program, to reduce this overhead on the runtime of same - that is, about optimisation in the case where it is not trivial.

Comment: @HansPassant Ah, thanks for the clarification. I do have the Microsoft antivirus running. It's usually sufficiently trouble-free that I don't even remember it's there. Is that what's causing the slowdown?

Comment: Very likely, though I have the vague impression that Windows also does some pre-processing on executables which might scale with file size.  You could uninstall the AV and see how much difference it makes; I'd be curious to hear the results.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Right, that turns out to be the explanation - disabling protection on that file cuts the time to 47 milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks for reporting back.  You might want to post your own answer.

Comment: 5 seconds is still a pretty good time for scanning a 256MB file, methinks (seeing how matching a hundred million or so signatures isn't precisely an entirely trivial task).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the delay is the Microsoft antivirus program scanning the executable each time it's run. Disabling protection on that file cuts the time to 47 milliseconds.